# Oracle server sandbox

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm doing a project for a database class (don't worry, it's not due tomorrow :P), and I need an Oracle server I can connect to. I'm trying to install it on my home box, but I'm slow with Linux. Really, I'd just like a sandbox server to connect to so I can run my homework assignments on them. Are those out there?

Comment: If your university does not provide you with equip labs for your assignments what are you paying for?

Comment: Ian: They probably don't provide the textbooks, notepads, or pencils either.

Comment: They have an Oracle server, but it's only available on campus. Silly.

Answer (score 5):

Why not try and use [a pre-built Oracle VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html) ?

Comment: I need to run PHP, JSP, and ASP.NET webapps on the server. Would that be easy to set up on one of those VMs?

Comment: You can just either use the VM just for Oracle or put the development environment on the host OS.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there aren't freely available Oracle instances you can access at your leisure -- there'd be patching and hacking attempts to deal with.  I don't see any revenue to gain from it, so it's very unlikely.

However, Oracle provides a free version (Express, currently 10g).  If you want an instance you can connect to at your whim, I'd suggest using a Virtual Machine (VM) software so you could create & run a VM, that would use a host OS of your choice, in order to install an Oracle Express instance that you could then connect to.  That, or setup a separate box for hosting Oracle from.

Comment: You can use apex.oracle.com as a sandbox for simple queries and APEX development. But you don't get direct connection to the database, only through the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the free version of Oracle XE easily from eDelivery.Oracle.com
It runs on windows and is dirt-simple to install.  Great platform for testing things out quickly.